# Get data from cosmos db resulted null with entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure-cosmosdb, asp.net-core-6.0

I have simple data in a container in cosmos db:

```
{
    "id": "fd81aacb-64eb-452b-a0bd-c0395aa8afb6",
    "thePartitionKey": "test"
}
```

When I try to list data with entity framework, it always returns null.

My DbContext looks something like this:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
   ..... //some configuration
   optionsBuilder.UseCosmos(endpoint, accountKey, dbName);
}
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   modelBuilder.Entity<Test>()
                .ToContainer("theContainerID")
                .HasPartitionKey(e => e.thePartitionKey);
   public DbSet<Test>? Tests { get; set; }
}
```

The Model:

```
public class Test
{
   public string id { get; set; }
   public string thePartitionKey { get; set; }
}
```

The code:

```
public List<Test> GetDataTest(){
   var qry = context.Tests.ToList();
   return qry;
}
```

I have looked at some tutorials [here](https://youtu.be/j5ylkjbJmu4), [here](https://github.com/dotnet/EntityFramework.Docs), and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/cosmos/planetary-docs-sample) but it does not really seem to be different from my code.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a similar example as shared by you in the question. In below screenshot you can see there is a single container in Cosmos DB having single record.

[image]

**Solution:-** As this container (theContainerId) stores a single document, there is no need of  discriminator. In case the container has document of same entity type, we can use HasNoDiscriminator() method of Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore package to get the record.

```
         modelBuilder.Entity<test>()
            .ToContainer("theContainerID")
            .HasPartitionKey(e => e.thePartitionKey)
            .HasNoDiscriminator();
```

Below is the screenshot of such an example.

[image]

As you can see, after modifying the modelBuilder the record is fetched.

[image]

It is explained in first link shared by you in question [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j5ylkjbJmu4) at 22:16 secs.

> Entity framework by default adds a discriminator value
> ("Discriminator" : "{modelName}" in current scenario it will be
> **test**) while creating the object, when you have multiple entity type of documents in the same cosmos DB container.

To get more information you can refer links available under reference section.

**References :-**

[EF Core Azure Cosmos DB Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/cosmos/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli)

[Azure CosmosDB + CRUD + Entity Framework Core - FREE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j5ylkjbJmu4)